# Rational Vector Assertion

Tags: c++, llvm

Below is the code in C++,

```
Num *= other.Den;
Den *= other.Num;
if (Den.isNegative()) {
    Num = -Num;
    Den = -Den;
}
assert(Den.isStrictlyPositive());
```

where Num and Den are of type LLVM::APInt.

For some reason I am getting the assertion failed. I have checked if the Denominator is negative explicitly and turned it positive. Can someone please let me in what scenario in this code, the assertion can fail? When I run my code against test case it fails. The test case is very large, and I have not been successful in cornering a particular case. The above code is a part of my algorithm which is doing some other job.

Here is the implementation of isStrictlyPositive. It is using the LLVM library file APInt.h.

```
bool isStrictlyPositive() const {
return isNonNegative() && !!*this;
}

bool isNonNegative() const {
return !isNegative();
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question based on the comment. What if the value is 0 is a good question. Thanks Jesse. Can you confirm if 0 is treated as positive or negative. The compiler is gcc

Comment: @Romaan: This has nothing to do with the compiler. [isStrictlyPositive](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1APInt.html#aeebb29dd5a7aaf9b4546fec69c43653b) is specified as "This tests if the value of this APInt is positive (> 0). Note that 0 is not a positive value."

Comment: Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm basing this off the following assumptions:

- Strictly positive means > 0
- `isNegative` is < 0

Given the snippet you quoted, the function `isStrictlyPositive` boils down to:

```
return isNonNegative() && !!*this;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
return !(*this < 0) && !!*this;
```

`!!*this` is equivalent to `!(!*this)` which is equivalent to `!(*this==0)` which is equivalent to `*this!=0`, so the expression is:

```
return !(*this < 0) && *this!=0;
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
return *this>=0 && *this!=0;
```

Which is really just:

```
return *this > 0;
```

So, your issue is that `Den` is `0` and is therefore not negative and not strictly positive.

Answer (score 2):

`0` is neither negative nor strictly positive.

Comment: Thanks Jesse and Mankarse. You Rock